# RequestFocus error: KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down

Tags: android

I have some code for a EditText field that works but this error is logged when I change the focus (focus changes as desired):

```
InputEventConsistencyVerifier      KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not  down
```

Can someone please explain why?

I read the InputEventConsistencyVerifier source that creates this error but I don’t understand how it occurs. I tried removing list.requestFocus().  But without that line, the focus stays on the EditText field.  However, removing the line does eliminate the error in the log.

```
public class AddDeleteActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private final String TAG = "AddDeleteName";

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e(TAG, "about to load fragment");

    setContentView(R.layout.add_delete_child_layout);

    Log.e(TAG, "finished loading fragment");

    final EditText nameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_child);

    nameTextField
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
˚               public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int    actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "onEditorAction: " + actionId);

                    String name = nameTextField.getText()
                            .toString();

                    Log.e(TAG, " name: " + name);

                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) v
                            .getContext().getSystemService(
                                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                            v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    Log.e(TAG, "change focus to List");
                    View list = findViewById(R.id.modchild_fragment);

 /*** FOLLOWING LINE GENERATES ERROR *****/
                    list.requestFocus();

                    return false;
                }
            });

}

}
```

the .xml:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/modchild_fragment"
    android:name="com.projectx.control.AddDeleteChild"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</fragment>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="enter launch codes"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, instead of calling `list.requestFocus`, you may want to use `nameTextField.clearFocus` as that more accurately conveys what you're trying to do.

Now, I don't know all the details of this specific error, but my guess is that `onEditorAction` is called by TextView synchronously, inside its handling of the `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_UP` event message. Calling `requestFocus` somewhere else may then disrupt the normal event flow for key presses. Again, that's just a guess.

What you could do is wrap your `list.requestFocus` call in a `Runnable`, and post that runnable to your event loop using [`Handler.post(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)). A common pattern is to hold a private field containing a Handler in your UI class (e.g. fragment or activity) for things like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
...
mHandler.post(...);
```

This will let the current event/message finish processing and only execute the Runnable (in this case a call to `list.requestFocus` after all other currently posted messages have been processed (this is usually only a few milliseconds).

And as I said above, try using `clearFocus` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  `.clearFocus()` produced the same error.  I'll try the handler approach.